# Ethernet-Connection ubuntu with VMware Player

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I installed VMware Player 7.1.2 on my Windows 7. On my VM I installed ubuntu 14.04. Now I have problems connecting to internet. With my computer I am connected with ethernet. Ubuntu can connect with it but I am not able to connect to internet. Which settings do I have to change. There are a lot of settings (VMware Player Network Adapter, IPv4 Settings and and and...) and I am not a pro ;-)

I tried it with NAT, Bridged, Host-only and Custom. I am not sure, if ubuntus connections settings are all right. Maybe the IPv4 Settings should not be Automatic (DHCP). But I have no clou, which addresses I could type in. I tried several ones.

Maybe VMware Player has the issue.

Comment: Please more information about your network and the subnets,